# Best Way to Postback Dynamic Table

Tags: asp.net, webforms, postback

I have a server-side table control. Since I don't know how many rows and columns it will have beforehand, I build the contents of this table in my pages `Form_Load` event handler.

That works well. But I'm populating that same table with textboxes, and I need to be able to read those textboxes if a submit button is clicked.

As it stands, it appears the table contents are cleared upon postback.

What is the best way to dynamically create textboxes in a table, and then read the values of those textboxes when the page is posted back?

Comment: You have to recreate all  dynamically created controls on postback in `Page_Load` at the latest and with the same ID's. Is there a reason for not using a web databound control like `GridView`(renders as table) or a `Repeater`?

Comment: But if I recreate the table, then won't the textboxes be reset and lose the edited values? I like the repeater control, but that would seem to impose the same problem. I still need to be able to read the edited values.

Comment: No, the values will be loaded from `ViewState` and events are triggered successfully  if you assign the same IDs and don't recreate the controls too late in the page's lifecycle.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Well, you lost me. If it's in ViewState, why would I need to recreate all the dynamically created controls? At any rate, my code that creates the table content sets the textbox values. So if I do that on the postback, those values will not represent what the user typed. Do you know of any links that explain what you are suggesting?

Comment: Have a look at msdn, e.g. according to the page's lifecycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.ASPX, this is also worth reading: [dynamic controls](http://tinyurl.com/oof7aaa) (also the first link included about `ViewState`).

Comment: Hmm... That link seems to simply describe the page lifecycle basics. I know about the basic page lifecycle and couldn't tell what relevant information I'm looking for. The second link appears to be broken.

Comment: I've already edited my comment, the link should work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16985472

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to persist the values on postback you will need to recreate the table control hierarchy on the `Page_Init` event. This usually means that you will need to rebind your table control to a data structure coming from the database.

Once the control hierarchy is in place, ASP.NET will load any data from the `ViewState`. This data can be in fact data that was previously set from the server on the textboxes. This step will ensure that these values are preserved on the control.

In the next step ASP.NET will process the POST data, and here basically will update the table textboxes with the input from the client (browser). Any values set from the ViewState will (most probably) be overwritten.

All this happens before `Page_Load`, so at this stage you should be able to access the client textboxes values.

Check out the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.ASPX), especially [this](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC386473.png) image.

Comment: I'm not connecting my table directly to a database. But you are saying I can populate the table, including setting the values of those textboxes, and ASP.NET will overwrite those values with the data being posted back? I'm testing that. Sorry, I'm pretty comfortable with the page lifecycle. Not seeing how that answers what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: The key here should be the reconstructing the control hierarchy at Page_Init. Then ASP.NET should be smart enough to map the values from the Request.Form object to the original ASP table. At least I hope so :)

Comment: Still testing. Actually, it seems to do what I understood you to be saying even if I construct the control in `Page_Load`. Also, this is in an ASCX control and it's appearance is affected by a property. So I can't construct the control before such properties have been set

Comment: So you are saying that in Page_Load the values from the browser are available right after rebuilding the table? That's would kind of weird. And about your ASCX: are you also loading it dynamically using LoadControl? In this case the loading of the ASCX should also be done in the Page_Init event.

Comment: I'm saying I can populate the table in `Page_Load`, and then I can read the user-entered value in my button's Click handler. The control is not loaded dynamically.